# Update if exist and insert if not in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following record in mongodb:

```
{"id": "123", "loc": "London", "dept": "CS"}
```

If i get a new record  with missing `"loc"` key as following :

```
{"id": "123", "dept": "CS"}
```

But Still i need to insert in mongo. I tried using `upsert = True`  in update_one method. I am confused with querying. I tried `{"id": "123"}` as filter. It is obvious that it sees `id:"123"` since it is there it was not inserting. So how can I write the filter for this problem. I am new to mongodb syntax.

Desired Outcome(filter should check `id` and `loc` for inserting or updating):

```
{{"id": "123", "loc": "London", "dept": "CS"}, {"id": "123", "dept": "CS"}}
```

I tried the following filter:

```
{"id": "123", "loc" :None}
```

it gave results as

```
{{"id": "123", "loc": "London", "dept": "CS"}, {"id": "123", "loc": null, "dept": "CS"}}
```

Here I don't want to have `loc : null` as well as result. I wanted to know how I should frame the filter

Comment: So, the uniqueness of a document is determined by its `id` *and* `loc`? Only records which have matching both should be considered equal? If either one differs (e.g. by being absent), they should be considered different? And given this, you want to update or insert documents into your database?

Comment: @deceze yeah true.

Answer (score 0):

This following filter actually worked:

```
{"id":"123", 'loc': {"$exists": False}}
```